# Axios catch won't call from express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm using express and react,
I'm doing a post request in Axios to the server and returning an error but the client won't catch it.

```
app.post('/add',  (req, res) => {
    entity.add(req.body).then(result => {
        res.status(200).send('works');
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error.message); // code runs here
    });
});
```

Client:

```
  axios.post(url, data).then(result => {
    }).catch(error => {
        alert(error);  // Code Doesn't reach here
    })
```

Please help...

Comment: How are you making it go into catch statement on server side? Maybe it's succeeding every time.

Comment: I debuged the code....

Comment: Does it recieve anything in the `.then` when it errors?

Comment: The then doesn't run also

Comment: Okay, so on the client side, when this code runs on a browser, can you check in the `Network` tab if there is a call being made to this and what response it returns in the browser. I think that could give us a better view on how the request is being handled.